# The final variable 'alignment' must be initialized

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

I have this error when I try to run Alignment.[image: Error in Alignment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `final` keyword stands for constant. Since it is a constant, not a variable, initialization is required. Remove the `final` keyword.

Because `final` is a constant keyword, its value cannot be changed.

There are two main keywords for constants: `const` and `final`. `const` is defined at compile time and `final` is defined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just  **Remove final keyword** .

**otherwise you can not assign any value** to **alignment** variable.

like this.

```
AlignmentDirectional alignment;
```